# how websphere liberty profile work with siteminder

Tags: siteminder, websphere-liberty

In my web application, need to use the siteminder implement the SSO with websphere liberty profile. But how to configure the liberty profile and siteminder and let them work smoothly? Hope your tips. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

WebSphere Liberty profile supports the Trust Association Interceptor (TAI) plug-point (similar to the full profile WebSphere) that a SiteMinder provided TAI implementation can be used to integrate with for SSO.
You can search for SiteMinder and WebSphere to get more information about their TAI implementation and integration with full profile. Configuration of TAI in the liberty profile is described [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc%2Fae%2Ftwlp_sec_tai.html)

Comment: Thanks for you replying. Another question: do you know whether or not the WebSphere Liberty profile TAI API is same as the Websphere application server? can I put the websphere application server TAI jar into liberty profile and use it directly?